# Rails creating a table without migration

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, create-table, rake-task

I have a rails app that has a particular table where the data and even the structure is dynamically generated outside of rails and ruby. This is by design, it is a special table where the structure is self-contained from the rest of active record and relationships. The models that work on it are also atomic. Again all by design, and purposeful. I don't not want a specific structure for this table, meaning that the column names and number of columns can change each time the table is initialized. If there are changes to the table structure I can manage the changes to my model class.

My issue is that the rails migration process seems to get in the way, and I don't want to have to keep stepping back and forth between migration and rollback, just to get the state of this single table reset.

The behavior I am looking for is literally every time I "generate" the data for this table I want to drop what table might already exist (in all environments: production, dev and test).

Is there a clear way to bypass the migration process? Or else create a special migration that is independent of the sequence of other migrations in the app?

The entire database is not disposable, but this one table is.

Thoughts on how I might achieve this behavior?

Rails 3, PostgreSQL database, git version control, heroku hosting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simple answer is "don't use migrations" -- they are designed to help you relatively gracefully extend an otherwise static database schema.  A migration does many things beyond generating/executing the data definition language (DDL) of your database -- it knows how to go forward and backward, knows by a linkage between source code (`schema.rb`) and data (in the `schema_migrations` table) how to determine which migrations need to be run, and so on.  All you need is the part that executes the DDL (which is, after all, just a kind of SQL).

And at least some of that part is [here in the TableDefinition API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html).  All of the infrastructure you might need seems to be present.

Comment: I guess it really is that simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can set this up as a rake task (it sounds like what you are using it as) that contains the SQL/rails commands used to construct the table, similar to what is done with `rake db:seed`

Comment: That worked I just put all the code into a rake task and I can change it as often as I need. Thanks.